# Emacs Pabbrev and Python

Tags: python, emacs, pabbrev

Normally when you hit tab on an empty line in emacs python mode it will cycle through the available tab indentations.  When I hit tab when the point is at the deepest indent level I get the pabbrev buffer containing the last best match options.  Does anyone else have this problem, is there an easy way around it without writing any elisp?

EDIT:
Trey, I want to keep pabbrev working in python mode not turn it off.

So lets say there are 2 indent levels, either none, or 1 level normally if it hit tab 3 times the first would put the point at 4 spaces in (or whatever indent is set to), the second back to 0 spaces, and the third back to 4 spaces.

With pabbrev mode on one indent puts the mark 4 spaces, the second brings up a buffer for autocomplete.  This should not happen if there is no letters to the left of my point.
Does that make any more sense?

Comment: So, you want TAB to not do pabbrev when there are just spaces to the left of the point?  And TAB should (in that case) just toggle between no indentation and 1 level (or cycle through the N possible levels)?

Comment: correct.  i would assume this is a common annoyance people have but maybe not.

Comment: Definitely need elisp for this.  I have it working, except the binding can't be TAB... gah.  wip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In light of the clarified requirements, you need something along the lines of this.  I'm pretty sure you can't get away w/out writing some elisp.  What's nice (IMO) is that this should work for all modes, not just python mode.

```
(defadvice pabbrev-expand-maybe (around pabbrev-expand-maybe-when-not-after-whitespace activate)
  "prevent expansion when only whitespace between point and beginning of line"
  (if (save-match-data
        (save-excursion
          (let ((p (point)))
            (string-match "^\\s-*$" (buffer-substring-no-properties (progn (beginning-of-line) (point)) p)))))
      (let ((last-command (if (eq last-command this-command) (pabbrev-get-previous-binding) last-command))
            (this-command (pabbrev-get-previous-binding)))
        (pabbrev-call-previous-tab-binding))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: I havent tried it yet, I am trying to get yasnippet working as well which puts me in a whole new tab hell.  hopefully i will be able to integrate your code once i get yasnippet and pabbrev working together.

Comment: pretty soon you won't have to do any real typing.  :)

Comment: This works like a charm, I am using it in Ruby Mode without any problems. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

How is this for a late response?

This should work out of the box now, thanks to a patch from Trey. Binding tab in the way that pabbrev.el is somewhat naughty, but what are you to do if you want rapid expansion.

Answer (score 0):

No elisp?  Sure:

```
M-x pabbrev-mode
```

should toggle it off.  But, if you don't mind cutting/pasting elisp, you can turn off pabbrev mode in python buffers:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode (lambda () (pabbrev-mode -1)))
```